# How to use crystal report in visual studio 2015 in C# using mysql?

Tags: c#, mysql, crystal-reports

I am doing an application which will print barcodes but I am struggling with the crystal report using MySql... 
I did everything which must be done to connect to mysql , create dataset connect it to Mysql etc but I can't show the values of the table in the report...

Need some help
Thank you.

**What I have tried:**

I used Dot Connect Mysql to connect it to the Dataset and I can see the values but not in the report...

Answer (score 0):

"There is a known issue with certain versions of Crystal Reports where the application is unable to open and browse tables and fields through an ODBC connection. Before using Crystal Reports with MySQL, please ensure that you have update to the latest version, including any outstanding service packs and hotfixes."[Here.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-odbc/en/connector-odbc-examples-tools-with-crystalreports.html)
We had to update to Crystal reports 2013 because of this issue.